# Error While getting authorization code from UPS Api

Tags: python, authentication, sandbox, ups

We are utilizing the UPS Authorization (OAuth) endpoint to obtain the authorization code.
We are using the following API endpoint:

`https://wwwcie.ups.com/security/v1/oauth/authorize`

Here are the query parameters we are using for this request:

```
client_id - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
redirect_uri - https://example.io/
response_type - code
```

We have attempted the request both with and without two optional parameters. Here are the optional parameters:

```
state - ups
scope - shipping(We have also tried different scope like rating, tracking, ship, etc.)
```

But we are getting following error:

```
Could not get any response
Failed to fetch

Why this might have happened:
- CORS is misconfigured on the server
- The server could not send a response
- No internet access
- Documentation issue - contact API owner
- Misconfigured security definition
```

Here is the link to the developer document and sandbox account that we are utilizing for this request:
https://developer.ups.com/api/reference?loc=en_US#operation/AuthorizeClient

We also attempted the provided Python code from their documentation, but it didn't generate any output.

```
import requests

url = "https://wwwcie.ups.com/security/v1/oauth/authorize"

query = {
  "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "redirect_uri": "https://example.io/",
  "response_type": "code",
  "state": "string",
  "scope": "tracking"
}

response = requests.get(url, params=query)

data = response.json()
print(data)
```

Could anyone please let me know which settings we need to be adjusted to resolve this issue?

Comment: show what you exactly get with `print(data)`. Did you use the same value in `redirect_uri` as you set in when you register on UPS API portal? Is your `https://example.io/` really exists? Did you check if UPS API send something to `https://example.io/` ? UPS API may send some information to `https://example.io/` to get confirmation - if it can't get response then it may not gives you access.

Comment: did you test your data using `curl` examples from documentation?

Comment: https://example.io/ does not exist. I replaced my original domain with a dummy domain. Yes, I attempted the curl command as specified in their documentation, but it did not return any response.

Comment: if `curl` doesn't give expected response then problem is setting, not Python code.

Comment: do you run it on local computer or on some server? Some serves may block access to external portals - to stop spamers/hackers/scrapers

Comment: I run it on live server and local server as well.